# Assignment of this keyword

Tags: javascript

I understand that when invoking a method of an object, the `this` value in that method is assigned to the object itself.

```
const dog = {
  age: 5,
  growOneYear: function () {
    this.age += 1;
  }
};

dog.growOneYear(); 
dog.age; // 6
```

That makes sense to me. However, when I try it a different way, it doesn't work:

```
function invokeTwice(cb) {
   cb();
   cb();
}

invokeTwice(dog.growOneYear);

dog.age;
// still 6
```

Why didn't this work?

Answer (score 2):

On the second example there is no object used to invoke `growOneYear()`.

You copy the method `growOneYear` into a new variable (`cb`). This looses the link between `dog` and `growOneYear`. You then call `cb()` as a regular function, without using an object to serve as `this` inside the method.

You said in the question:

> ... when invoking a method of an object, the `this` value in that method is assigned to the object itself.

The statement above is correct and it explains why it doesn't work when you invoke `growOneYear` as `cb()`: it is "a method of an object" only when it is invoked as `dog.growOneYear()`. If you copy it into `cb` and call it as `cb()` it is just a regular function; no object is used to call it any more.

The situation you describe in the questoin is even listed in the documentation of [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Creating_a_bound_function):

> A common mistake for new JavaScript programmers is to extract a method from an object, then to later call that function and expect it to use the original object as its `this` (e.g. by using that method in callback-based code). Without special care, however, the original object is usually lost.

`Function.prototype.bind()` is the solution to your problem:

```js
const dog = {
  age: 5,
  growOneYear: function () {
    this.age += 1;
  }
};

dog.growOneYear(); 
console.log(dog.age);       // 6

function invokeTwice(cb) {
   cb();
   cb();
}

// Bind the method to the desired object
// Inside `invokeTwice()`, `cb` is the function `dog.growOneYear` with
// `this` pointing to `dog` ------+
//                                v
invokeTwice(dog.growOneYear.bind(dog));

console.log(dog.age);       // 8
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second case,your function will be passed the window object as the this parameter since you are not invoking the cb function passed with any specified object.

In case you want to invoke with your dog object use apply like this.

```
enter code here
const dog = {
 age: 5,
 growOneYear: function () {
 //console.log(this)
 this.age += 1;
 }
};

dog.growOneYear(); 
dog.age;

function invokeTwice(cb) {
  cb.apply(dog);
  cb.apply(dog);
}

invokeTwice(dog.growOneYear);

console.log(dog.age);
```